# Implement Split method with a function

Tags: javascript, function, split, jsbin

I want to implement the split method with a function

This is what i am trying to achieve

```
var string = 'aa,bb,c';

var separator = ',';

var stringList = string.split(separator);

function splitString() {
  console.log(stringList);
}
```

This returns this `array`

```
["aa", "bb", "c"]
```

I am trying to implement the same with a function but it returns an empty `array [] and not ["aa", "bb", "c"]`

I have created a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/mejayuv/edit?html,js,console,output) for who can help out.

```
function split(string,separator) {
  var cache = [];
  var cachInt = 0;
  var lastWord = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if(string[i] === separator) {
        cachInt++
        lastWord = ''
    }
    else {
      lastWord = lastWord + string[i];
      cache[cachInt] == lastWord;
    }
  }
  return cache;
}


function splitString() {
  console.log(split('string, separator',','));
}
```

Comment: Is this for practise? Then it's a good exercise. If this is suposed to be real code, then please dont :) this is inefficient

Comment: it is for training

Comment: jsbin underlined your exact error in my browser. You're using `==` instead of `=` on the line `cache[cachInt] == lastWord;`

Comment: You want `cache[cachInt] = lastWord` not `cache[cachInt] == lastWord`, although I'm not sure why you'd ever do this instead of using the built in split method.

Answer (score 2):

You do this:

```
cache[cachInt] == lastWord;
```

Which should be, because you're not comparing, you're assigning:

```
cache[cachInt] = lastWord;
```

---

While we're at it, there is room for improvement. Your version has the line mentioned above. That line gets run *every iteration of `i`*. Thats not really needed, as you only want to perform a save on a split:

```
if(string[i] === separator) {
    cache[cachInt] = lastWord; // Only assign when we find a seperator
    cachInt++
    lastWord = ''
} else {
    lastWord = lastWord + string[i];
}
```

This has a tiny issue: The last part of string often doesn't have the seperator, it's `a,b,c` and not `a,b,c,`.
We can fix that easily with a check after the `for` to see if you have anything remaining:

```
if( lastWord!=='' ){
     cache[cachInt] = lastWord;
}
return cache;
```

This has the added feature that it works as a `rtrim()` (wether you want that or not is up to you to fix).

Also, if you don't need to support older IE versions, then don't use `var`, use `let`. If you want to know why, [this question explains it well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444416/2519416).

---

Then, you're using a counter to remember which `cachInt` to use. As we now only use it once per "cacheInt", eg once per word, we know that each addition is +1, and only happens once per word. We also don't really care about the index, we just want each word to be added once. So, you can do `cache[] = lastWord`, or use push, which is slightly neater: `cache.push(lastWord)`.
By removing the use for this counter, you can also remove the `cachInt++` and the `let/var cachInt` at the beginning of the function, resulting in smaller code.

Result of all of the above:

https://jsbin.com/mejayuv/1/edit?html,js,console,output